# Codeigniter - Load a view and update it dynamically in another view

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I am loading two views from a single controller

```
student controller     student_edit view  ---> on submit inserts data 
edit()             --->
loads 2 views           comments view      ---> should dynamically insert data and reload it
```

So basically I need to add a comment box my **student_edit** page. 
Here is a snapshot :
[image: Student_edit view does the default action. Only the comments should be added dynamically]

I have tried the following piece of code but doesnt seem to be working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();
                $('.submitComment').submit(function(e){
                    e.preventdefault()
                    $.ajax({
                        url : baseurl + 'index.php/comment/insert',
                        data : $('form').serialize(),
                        type: "POST",
                        success : function(comment){
                            $(comment).hide().insertBefore('#insertbeforMe').slideDown('slow');
                        }
                    })
                    return false;
                })
            })
```

**PROBLEM :** The above code reloads the whole view and **student_edit form** is also getting submitted.

Can anyone please help me out how I can add and reload the comments dynamically ?

Comment: So the problem is that `e.preventDefault();` isn't working? I would make sure you write it with a capital D and add the semicolon just to be sure. Also, is `.submitComment` the class of your `<form>` element?

Comment: @Jeemusu : I corrected the mistake. And .submitComment is the class of my div tag which is outside the <form> element

Comment: The problem now is that on submit no event is taking place

Comment: I'm guessing you've corrected the jQuery so that it is now `$('.form_elements_class').submit(function(e){` I would add an `alert('test')` to the top of your `success:` callback. If it is called it would appear your AJAX request is fine. Also check your console for errors, and your network tab for XHR activity to see what response your getting from the AJAX request. You may want to post your comment controllers insert method to, so we can take a look.

Comment: Hey yeah got it.. you were right.. I check the XHR tab and corrected the mistake.. Thanks alot for the help !!

Comment: you can create a div with the content then when you want you can use $.load of jquery to load contents in the div

Comment: hard to tell without seeing any of the dom structure....

Answer (score 2):

create some ajax controller which loads only views,

```
  class Ajax_Controller extend CI_Controller(){
    function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
    //here you can check if request is ajax, if not ajax make some redirect to not show the url browsing
     }
    function ajaxview(){
    $this->load->view('myajax-view');
    }

    }
```

then, everytime you need to load that view,
you can do a jquery simple load for your right view modules:

```
$('#right-div').load('site.com/ajax_controller/ajaxview');
```